# Как остановить ДДоС атаку

Tags: безопасность, ddos

Добрый день. Нужна помощь.

Конкуренты достали (мои некоторые сайты занимают нормальные позиции в "гугл") и по этому делают разные пакости. Очень много делают отказов на сайты, но это ерунда.

Три дня назад получил письмо, вот такого содержания:

> Тема: Здравствуйте. На выделенный адрес аккаунта хххх мы наблюдаем 
>   мощную  входящую ДДоС атаку 20Гб/с и 5 млн пакетов/с.  Доступ к
>   данному адресу заблокирован. Просим Вас проанализировать  причины
>   данной ситуации  и проккоментировать ситуацию и объяснить причины
>   возникшей ситуации.

Сайт до сих пор не работает. Я им написал, что моей вины нет, просил включить, ответили:

> Ограничения мы можем снять не ранее чем через 24 часа с данного
>   адреса, так как атака  на текущий момент активна и создает сложности в
>   работе сетевого канала и сервера хостинга.

Мне они посоветовали:

> Вы можете воспользоваться услугами специальных сервисов защиты от
>   "ДДоС".

Скажите пожалуйста:

- возможно ли остановить эту входящую "ДДоС" атаку, чтобы сайт заработал?
- какую поставить защиту на сайты или перенести на какой- нибудь
  специальный сервис?

Одним словом, сделать что нибудь, чтобы это все прекратилось.

Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Поменять IP, воткнуть CloudFlare и новый IP нигде не светить, например

Comment: бывает ещё, что ддоса никакого нет, а просто проплатили хостеру. И это нужно проверить.

Comment: Хостера меняйте, а этого в черный список.

Comment: Вчера вечером так и сделали, воткнули CloudFlare, сайт заработал. Но сегодня утром опять ....

Comment: @Maxfort значит, где-то засветили ip-адрес

Comment: Отслеживать и фильтровать входящий трафик.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос в текущей формулировке я считаю слишком общим что бы дать на него конкретный ответ, тем не менее для комментария моё сообщения получилось слишком длинным, поэтому публикую его всё же ответом.

---

DDoS атаки крайне различны, соответственно меры протитводействия так же отличаются. На текущий вопрос ответ может быть или слишком длинным или слишком общем. В качестве более-менее универсальной могу дать такую рекомендацию - если у вас нет контроля над оборудованием на который идёт атака (т. е. атакуют не ваши сервера, а сервера хостера), то направьте все запросы на ваши сайты через специализированные ресурсы - CloudFlare, DDoSGuard и аналогичные (это не реклама, а примеры, за качество их работы не ручаюсь). Правильно сделать это нужно будет таким образом:

- заказать у хостера новый IP;
- сменить A записи домена(-ов) или NS сервера на принадлежащие выбранному сервису по защите от DDoS;
- указать в настройках сервиса новый выделенный IP;
- НИГДЕ более новый адрес не указывать, что бы не засветить;
- сообщить хостеру о проделанных действиях, попросить блокировать (если есть возможность) все обращения к скомпрометированному IP. Или, по крайней мере, убедиться что сайт принимает теперь обращения только по новому IP (который известен лишь сервису по защите от атак).

Обратите внимание! Это - не остановка DDoS атаки. Это - лишь её фильтрация. Остановлена в данном случае она будет лишь тогда, когда у конкурентов кончатся деньги или они убедятся в её неэффективности. Ну или если вы первыми сдадитесь.

Если же решите менять хостера, то вначале у нового хостера уточните, смогут ли они зафильтровать такую атаку. Это сбережёт и вам время и будет честно по отношению к новому хостеру.